# Split image into separate rows

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, background

I am attempting to create a animation effect which cannot be done with CSS transforms, CSS filters or any sort of altering CSS properties over time (jquery animate style)

What I am doing requires me to be able to animate each row of an image seperatly from each other.

I have thought of 2 ways to do this

A)
Create a DIV for each row of the image, set the image as the background for each DIV and use background-position to make each row only show the correct row of the background image. 
This solution would use Javascript to set the width of each DIV to the width of the image, to create each div dynamically in a loop ect

B)
Use a canvas element for each row of the image and use Image() and createImageBitmap() to read the image file and canvas.drawImage() to paint the correct row of the image into each canvas.

I have 3 questions

1)
Are there any other options which i have not considered?

2)
Is ether one of these significantly faster than the other?

3)
I intend to make use of CSS transition Scale X/Y to adjust the width of each row during my animation and I want it to automatically stretch the image to fit (without obviously chopping a bit off or messing up the aspect ratio)
Will my two options allow me to do this?

Comment: 1. Not sure. 2. Two div would be significantly faster. (Since second uses javascript) But won't affect too much in your case. 3. Only the first one allows you to do it. Canvas element would require you to write customized js animation.

Answer (score 0):

- 1: Yes there are. SVG is an option, so is webGL. If the animation is static then a video may do the trick. There are other options but they have limited support or are outdated technologies.
- 2: The DOM (includes HTML, and CSS) and the canvas use the same hardware to render pixels to the screen. They for the most part can both get the same thing done at about the same rate. Generally a competent programer can get more out of the canvas than from the DOM, though this is partly to do with the fact that the canvas presents a far simplier interface than the DOM. Using the canvas allows you to sidestep much of the unneeded overhead that can not be avoided when using the DOM.
- 3: Mixing canvas and CSS on the most part is not the best solution. As mentioned in question two's answer the same hardware is used to render pixels. The resulting rendering is of the same quality. If you are using the canvas you will be using the inbuilt transformations already, adding CSS animations on top of that means more work for the browser, effectively doubling the amount of processing that is needed per pixel, that is best done once when rendering via the canvas 2D API.

From what you describe the solution is most easily done via Javascript and the canvas. I would imagine the total amount of code to be less than the total amount for the CSS/HTML/Javascript version and would be more flexible. But I am a programer of many many years and it is second nature for me to write code. If you are an inexperienced coder such a task can present many problems and take considerable amount of time to implement, with the real risk of bugs being an ongoing headache.

The same is also true for CSS, HTML, and the DOM.

You must choose how to implement projects like these not based on what is the best possible solution, but rather what method are you most experienced with and confident in using. The difference in performance is minor between two equally good implementations, but the difference is significant when one method is your first attempt